# Converting Object to DOM returns [Object object]

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm attempting to create a factory function inside an IIFE for turning an object template into an HTML structure and inserting it into the DOM.

Here is my code so far.

```
const InfoGen = (() => {

    const content = document.querySelector(".content");
          
    const domElement = obj => {
        
        let domEl = document.createElement(obj.tag)
        
        if (obj.content) domEl.innerText = obj.content;
        
        if (obj.classes) for (let cssClass of obj.classes) {
            domEl.classList.add(cssClass)
          
        };
        if (obj.tag == "img") {
            domEl.src = "logo";
        }
        if (obj.children) for (let child of obj.children) {
            domElement(child)
            domEl.append(child)                     
        };   
        return domEl;
    }   

    const headerTemplate = {

        tag: 'div',
        classes: ['header'],
        children: [
            {
                tag: 'img',
                src: 'logo',
                classes: ['logo'],
            },
            {
                tag: 'h1',
                content: `Clams n' Cabbage`,
            },
            {
                tag: 'h2',
                content: `the finest clams n cabbage the world did ever taste!`,
            }
        ]
    }
    let gen = domElement(headerTemplate);
    content.appendChild(gen)


})();
```

However the output of the final line when console logged is:

```
main.js:formatted:32 
<div class=​"header">​"[object Object]""[object Object]""[object Object]"</div>​
```

Could someone point out where I am going wrong? I understand that these objects are just being printed as strings, but I can't figure out where I fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: `domElement(child)` doesn't **modify** `child`, it creates something new and returns it. So when you do `domEl.append(child)` afterward, you're appending the object, not the result of `domElement`. Instead, append the result of `domElement`: `domEl.append(domElement(child))`. (But I haven't done a thorough code review to see whether there are other issues.)

Comment: Side note: I suggest reading through some JavaScript tutorials to find out where `;` go. Your code leaves them off most of the time (which is allowed in many cases because of Automatic Semicolon Insertion) but then includes them at times they aren't needed (such as after the block on an `if`)...sometimes. I recommend learning the rules and then either following them (my suggestion), or relying on ASI in an informed manner (just be sure you know the gotchas).

Comment: Thanks, that's solved it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I also appreciate your side note about the semicolons. I will try and broaden my understanding here. I thought that `;` might need to go at the end of each if block as that exits from it (having the `;` between an `if` and `else` results in an error, from experience)

Comment: A very reasonable thought. :-) Basically: `;` is a statement terminator. You need it at the end of any statement *except* (there's always a catch!) a statement with a block attached to it. So `if (...) { }` doesn't need one because it has a block (`{ ... }`). There's a bit more to the rules than that, but that'll get you started. :-) Happy coding!